# Registration,Forgot password form show blank screen after submit

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, register

If we submit register and forgot password form it display blank screen. But refreshing the page submit the data and display success screen.Could not understand what is the problem? please help!

Comment: First confirm that compilation is enable or disable ?

Comment: compilation is disable

Comment: check in console any errors are displaying.

Comment: how can I check console errors?

Comment: Which browser you are used ?

Comment: ok. No errors are displaying in browser console.

Comment: Delete cache, check system logs if any errors are showing in.

Comment: try all these options. Nothing found. By debugging I got that Magento core mail function not working. But I have never modified core mail function.

Comment: Enable error and check it.

Comment: Error enable from index.php ?

Comment: yes. No error displays.

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443503/supee-6788-and-password-reset-blank-page may be help you.

Comment: I have not installed any security patches.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A blank screen can be caused by two potentials. 
Most likely there are other reasons. But these are the most common:

PHP fatal error. check your webserver error logs. Where these are located is highly dependent on your server setup.

another common reason is that there are no layout handles configured in xml to deal with the controller action.

I am leaning towards the first in your case.

You can also try the following:

SSH to your server. 
Cd to magento-root/var/log folder.
Issue command : tail -f *.log

This will watch all log files in that folder and display any changes that happen, as they happen.

Do the noted actions that causes blank screen.

It may help to include the web server logs in the tail.

Hope that shows you something.

Comment: var log folder is empty.No error log file is created.

Comment: Enable debug log under system-configuration-developer